# Reassign many [time]-tagged questions

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, retagging

It seems to me that the [time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag should be used for questions pertaining to the *usage* of time, or about time itself, such as [Davening schedule for someone with a night shift](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70927/davening-schedule-for-someone-with-a-night-shift), or [Is bitul zman (wasting one's time) a formal prohibition?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70922/is-bitul-zman-wasting-ones-time-a-formal-prohibition), or even [The time periods of the Acharit HaYamim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68896/the-time-periods-of-the-acharit-hayamim).

But many questions under the [time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag seem to be more fit for [shiurim-measurements](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiurim-measurements), as they discuss *how much time* an event takes/requires, such as [How early can I take down my mezuzos before a move?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73140/how-early-can-i-take-down-my-mezuzos-before-a-move), [Source for waiting between milk and meat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71649/source-for-waiting-between-milk-and-meat), [Matza eating time limit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70182/matza-eating-time-limit) (which actually has both [time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [shiurim-measurements](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiurim-measurements)), [How long are brachot applicable to a given food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67877/how-long-are-brachot-applicable-to-a-given-food), etc.

Thoughts? Should we leave the tag as-is, or should we make a stricter definition for the tag?

Comment: What's wrong with having questions about time shiurim be tagged [tag:time] and [tag:shiurim-measurements]?

Comment: I tagged http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69548 with 'time' not "because it mentions in passing that the guy won't be home for a few days" but because the crux of the question is whether _mishloach manos_ can be dropped off of received at the wrong time.

Comment: This question would be improved if it included examples from [main] in its second paragraph.

Comment: @IsaacMoses By that logic we should also have a [tag:volume], [tag:area], [tag:length], etc. Ein ladavar sof.

Comment: @DonielF If you think it would be worthwhile to consider questions about "volume" as a collection, it could be worthwhile to create a tag with that name.